# Should research papers that require millions of dollars to development be evaluated on the same track as those that do not?

Tags: publications, conference, funding, industry, academic-freedom

I have previously asked many questions on the encroachment of tech industry on academic research in the past few years [[1]](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/103171/fear-of-missing-out-how-to-maintain-a-good-attitude-towards-research-in-academi), [[2]](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84365/is-machine-learning-causing-a-brain-drain-in-math-science-and-engineering-acade) I am here again because this encroachment not only hasn't stopped, but accelerated.

The latest is the news that GPT-3 developed by Open AI won the best paper award in NeurIPS 2020. https://openai.com/

Open AI is backed by at-least 1 billion dollar of Microsoft funding. This software/program required countless millions of dollar to develop, the kind of funding that is only available to tech companies. The research is not reproducible and proprietary. A estimate is that it would required $12,000,000 - $1,900,000 USD for any individual (in academia) to redevelop this model from scratch.

Given that it has won a best paper award, it begs one to question whether if academia can ever compete on the same level as these multi-million dollar companies. These large tech companies can continuously pour millions into these projects and create ever more impressive results with far reaching impact on society. In light of all this, should these type of research be evaluated on the same track as regular (say, theoretical) papers in terms of awards and other metrics?

Comment: "the kind of funding that is only available to tech companies" Most nation states can easily supply that level of uinding. They just choose not to.

Comment: That's not actually much money for a scientific project.  JWST has spent $10 billion and has no results yet.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope#Cost_and_schedule_issues

Comment: Imho the ethical questions are a more serious issue about the leadership of private research. Commercial interests don't always match societal advance: in ML applications there are issues with racist bias in military/police applications, increasing socio-economic inequalities, etc. Moreover the general lack of transparency, which is a given in a private economy context, is often detrimental to the general public.

Comment: Plenty of science has budgets in that range

Comment: Industrial researcher here. Believe me, few of us have this kind of budget.

Answer (score 16):

I feel your question approaches this topic from an unhealthy, competitive perspective: I think the most important thing to keep in mind is that science is about **progress**, not about a fair distribution of NeurIPS papers, awards, or other brownie points. We accept papers because they expand our knowledge, and we award those that (subjectively) do so by the largest margin. Whether a single person working in their office has generated this knowledge or a team at a company does not change the knowledge that's being produced. In that light, excluding companies from academic research (effectively because they are being too good at it) is silly.

That said, your specific question asks whether there should be different "tracks" (I guess either actual conference tracks or completely separate conferences would qualify) for papers that need a lot of monetary investment. This can certainly be useful, and in my experience it often happens fairly naturally - either because an industry track gets created and gains importance over the years (as happening for instance at [ICSE](https://conf.researchr.org/home/icse-2020) with its Software Engineering in Practice track), or because an academic conference gets more and more industry interest until it essentially becomes an industry conference with an academic track (this has arguably happened with [WWW](https://www2020.thewebconf.org) and maybe NeurIPS, although I don't know enough about NeurIPS to be able to tell).

However, you may not like the result very much - once you push all those expensive and highly practical contributions into a separate thread, you may find that people actually value these papers higher than your (now clearly earmarked) theoretical academic papers. The end result may be that the highest-prestige tracks or conferences are the ones where you as an academic aren't even the target audience anymore. The top conference of my field, ICSE, isn't quite there yet (the research track is still higher-prestige than the industry track), but you can already today observe that *attendance* in industry track talks is higher than in research sessions.

That said (and this brings me back to the opening paragraph), I'm not sure what the problem is. At the end of the day we should be happy that the field progresses and that people are interested in what's being produced. As long as academic contributions in the field are still useful and valuable, meetings, conferences will remain available. And it pays to remember that academics rarely compete directly with industry anyway (say in the context of jobs, promotions, or grants).

Comment: I think the real problem with the Open AI paper, is not that it cost millions of dollars to develop, but that the code/algorithm/results are not public. As you say, we accept papers because they expand our knowledge. But without detailed descriptions/code of what OpenAI have done, is them saying "look at all the amazing things we can do that you can't" really expanding our knowledge?

Comment: +1 to @IanSudbery's comment. In light of which the question should really be whether it is appropriate to award papers that rely on proprietary methods that are not even described in the paper. Whether these methods come from industry, or from an academic closed shop should not matter in this kind of assessment.

Comment: @IanSudbery that may be, but that's decidedly not what OP asked about.